# How to filter list if the "value" have a "null" or "0" in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, filter

I have a list like this:

```
listOf(1, null, 0)
```

And I filter it with this:

```
_currentSource.value?.filter { it.nominalAmount != null || it.nominalAmount != 0 } as List<SourceDanaInvestasi>
```

But the filter it's not working because when I save it to Room and show it, in my app show all value `(1, null, 0)`

So how to filter it to send the data only without `null` or `0`?

Comment: what is nominalAmount, is it `Double?` instead of `Int?`?

Comment: `Int?` sorry forgot to edit on my question

Comment: try `filter{ it.nominalAmount != null && it.nominalAmount != 0 }` as you should cover two cases

Comment: What is the type of `value`? It is evidently not `List<Int?>` like your example `listOf(1, null, 0)`, because you are calling some property on the items `.nominalAmount` without even using a null-safe call.

Comment: @MohammedAlaa you right, it's work with `&&`, but why using `||` it's not working

Comment: @Tenfour04 it;s `list` from my `model` and in the model have a list of data like `nominalAmount` but I need to filter it with `null` or `0` to don't save it to Room

Comment: @RRifaFauziKomara when `nominalAmount` is null it is not 0, when it is 0 it is not null. So one of them is true and resulting value is then true. That's why all the elements are present in the filtered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result, you are filtering, which creates a new list, and then dumping the result on the floor.

```
_currentSource.value = _currentSource.value?.filter {
    it.nominalAmount != null && it.nominalAmount != 0
} as List<SourceDanaInvestasi>
```

You also need to change the `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

To filter out `0` and `null` from your list:

```
val items = listOf(1, 0, null)
val filteredItems = items
    .filterNotNull()
    .filter { it != 0 }
```

Kotlin Playground: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjUwIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBpdGVtcyA9IGxpc3RPZigxLCAwLCBudWxsKVxuXHRcbiAgICB2YWwgZmlsdGVyZWRJdGVtcyA9IGl0ZW1zXG4gICAgLmZpbHRlck5vdE51bGwoKVxuICAgIC5maWx0ZXIgeyBpdCAhPSAwIH1cblxuICAgIHByaW50KGZpbHRlcmVkSXRlbXMpXG59IiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiJ9

Comment: In the `filterNotNull()` have a warning with the message `Useless call` and better to delete it. So I think it will not work

Comment: Might be a overhead because creating a completely new list by filtering nulls and then filtering again, i.e. iterating twice over the list.

Comment: in my code have `_currentSource.value?` so in the `filterNotNull()` have a warning with the message `Useless call`.

Comment: @RRifaFauziKomara might be because _currentSource.value might not return a non-nullable list, check its type.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu This would be a overhead as it creates two lists. You can also use it as a sequence so it just operates on the result rather than a list.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat Yep, Cheers!